# Vistual Studio VSTO Outlook Add-in: Add custom group to specific Tab

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, ribbon

I've been able to create an addin for outlook and have added a Ribbon (Visual Designer) and set a custom tab and a few controls. The thing is i need it to be on a specific view.
In this case, i need it to be on the meeeting and appointment views.

First i click on the Calendars view on outlook:

[image: Calendar View]

Then, whenever i click on any appointment or meeting, and i need to have a custom icon on that place:
[image: Place for the custom icon]
[image]

Is this possible? I've tried with some ControlId Settings but none seems to get the job done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Your ribbon XML must specify the appropriate built-in tab (see `TabAppointment` below) and the built-in group (see `insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard"` below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="OnLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAppointment">
        <group id="id1" label="Infor CRM" visible="1" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard" getImage="GetImage">
          <toggleButton id="id2" size="large" getLabel="OnGetLabel" getImage="GetImage" getPressed="OnGetButtonPressed" screentip="tip" supertip="supertip" onAction="OnToggleButtonClick" getEnabled="GetEnabled"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Is it possible with Ribbon (Visual Designer) instead of XML ?

Comment: Yes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-change-the-position-of-a-tab-on-the-ribbon?view=vs-2019

Comment: I have already tried that out, but it simply doesn't show up where it is supposed. I can manage to make the custom group show on the appointment itself (double clicking the event will show up the custom group) but i need it to be on "Calendar tools > appointment" (this tab shows up whenever an appointment is simply selected but not opened).

Comment: Then you need to work with the Explorer ribbon, not Inspector.

Comment: I've tried plenty of combinations but none worked so far...

Comment: You need to show how you set up your Explorer ribbon.